# Scroll duration when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am using Jquery to create an effect that will change things as the user scrolls

```
$(function() {
    var headerPosition = $(".home-header");
    $(window)
        .scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window)
                .scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 200) {
                headerPosition.addClass("home-header-color");
            } else if (scroll <= 600) {
                headerPosition.removeClass("home-header-color");
            }
        });
});
```

This is what i'm using a simple add remove class function that gets triggered on a certain scroll amount.

What I want to do is to make it as a user scrolls once no matter how fast.

This is what I came up with but dose not work well scrolling up.

## [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Space_Invader161/pen/QBpPMO)

I want it to only appear when you reach the top of the screen when scrolling up. Not on just one scroll up.

I tried combining the two but it didn't work out well.